# Grunt copy error - No "copy" targets found

Tags: gruntjs

I've got the following in my gruntfile.coffee:

```
copy: {
        main: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'js/no-concat/',
        src: '**',
        dest: 'deploy/public_html/assets/javascripts/',
        flatten: true,
        filter: 'isFile',

        }
      }
```

And when i run "grunt copy" from the command line to test it, it says:

> > > No "copy" targets found. Warning: Task "copy" failed. Use --force to continue.

I have tried every variation under the sun to no avail.

Please help :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above isn't valid Coffeescript. Try this one:

```
module.exports = (grunt)->
  grunt.initConfig

    copy:
      main:
        expand: true
        cwd: 'js/no-concat/'
        src: '**'
        dest: 'deploy/public_html/assets/javascripts/'
        flatten: true
        filter: 'isFile'
```

Comment: You know, i swear i tried that syntax style. I must have had a bad indentation somewhere i guess! Thanks Ben, really appreciate it!!